# How to convert a series which is in string format to integer

Tags: python

Code:

```
E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'] = E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'].apply(lambda x: 
                                            "${:,.0f}".format(int(float(x))))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,153.00'
```

Input:

```
E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt']
Out[57]: 
0         110.00
1         168.00
2         240.00
3         101.00
4         360.00
5         143.00
6         125.00
7         431.00
8         683.00
9         102.00
10        103.00
11        209.00
12        285.00
13        365.00
```

So far it is not working, i would expect no error, but error keeps occurring.

Comment: `x = x.replace(',','')`

Comment: E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt']=E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'].replace(',','')
E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'] = E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'].apply(lambda x: "${:,.0f}".format(int(x)))

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '110.00'

Comment: You used `float`, not `int`.

Comment: even with float it is not working

Comment: E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt']=E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'].replace(',','')
E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'] = E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'].apply(lambda x: "${:,.0f}".format(int(float((x)))))

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,153.00'

Comment: I told you. Your string contains `,`. You should remove it. `format(float(x.replace(',', '')))` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt']=E4G3G['Pmhoprepatt'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

You can use `str` accessor's `replace` method, to replace, then convert to float.

Output will be as expected.